# Destructuring type hints

Tags: python, casting, type-hinting

I'm looking for a neat way to use Python's type hints to cast a non-trivial type.

For example, casting from a simple type.

```
a = '5'
b: int = None

__annotations__['b'](a)  # <int 5>
```

However, I don't know how to go about parsing more complex things like below.

```
b: Optional[int] = None

__annotations__['b']  # typing.Union[int, NoneType]
```

There must be a way to parse these back out for the type annotations to be useful to things like IDEs.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that functionality is not yet written and certainly not in the standard library. It's probably doable, but you'll have to implement it. Typings so far are mainly for validation, rather than conversion - for example, if something is typed as a `Sequence` what concrete type should it be? How about union types?

Answer (score 0):

Edit after clarification:

Based on your comment, I think you're asking how an application (e.g., an IDE) parses the type annotations in order to check whether some code is compatible with them.

The answer is: that's the main job of a PEP 484-compliant static type checker, such as mypy. Mypy has ~50k lines of code, so it's not exactly trivial. Theoretically, an IDE could use mypy, get all the error messages from it, and then mark the corresponding code as incorrect. In practice, though, PyCharm and WingIDE implement roughly equivalent functionality from scratch.

If you need to parse and validate type hints for your own project, just use [mypy API](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#integrating-mypy-into-another-python-application).

If you just need to parse the type annotations, without actually verifying whether they are correct, you can use the [typed_ast module](https://github.com/python/typed_ast).

Original answer:

Casting in the sense of type hints is intended to tell the type checker that the variable is a different type than it thinks, due to the limited understanding the type checker has of your program. It says nothing about how to convert things from one type to another, and in the vast majority of cases, the conversion is either ambiguous or impossible. For example, what do you want the result of these "casts" to be:

```
from typing import Dict
a = 5
b: Dict[int, int]
__annotations__['b'](a)  # ??? (impossible)
c: Union[str, float]
__annotations__['c'](a)  # ??? (ambiguous)
```

I was trying to guess what you meant by "parsing type annotations for IDEs", but could not. Maybe you can clarify more? IDEs (such as PyCharm and WingIDE) already parse type annotations quite well, and use them, for example, to auto-complete identifiers while you type.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the wording. I mean IDEs are able to see `Union[str, float]` (say as a function parameter) and know when to throw a warning if you pass it something like `a = {}`. To do so, that IDES must be deconstructing the type annotation into its component parts (Union, str, float). Does that make sense. I see your point about not being and to cast to it reliably and that's OK. Thanks for digging up this question

Comment: mypy link seems to have changed to https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending_mypy.html